# Largest irreducible representation of a finite non-commutative group

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite non-commutative group of order $k$. Is there any way to determine a number $m$ such that there will necessarily exist an irreducible representation of $G$ of dimension $d \geq m$? If not, what kind of additional information could give an answer? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Take $m=2$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant to ask for $d\le m$. There's certainly an irreducible representation of dimension less than $\sqrt k$, but I have no idea how good an estimate that is.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Actually, given a non-commutative finite group, I am trying to see that it has certain "large" irreducible representations.

Comment: Then maybe the comment by @Dustan is what you want. Look at the dihedral groups of order a multiple of 4. Aren't their irreducible representations all dimension 1 and 2?

Comment: @GerryMyerson that's true of every dihedral group, not just the ones of order a multiple of 4.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein I was very vaguely hoping that some lower bound could be given in general depending on the order of the abelianization of the group.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was very vaguely hoping that some lower bound could be given in general depending on the order of the abelianization of the group.

Comment: If $G$ acts on a set $S$ of size $n$ and the action is doubly transitive, then there is an irreducible representation of  dimension $n-1$: if $V$ is the monomial representation coming from the action of  $G$ on $S$, the $G$ stable complement to $V^G$ is irreducible. e.g. $G= A_n$ for $n \ge  4$ has an irreducible representation of dim $n-1$.Is this useful to you?

Comment: Well, the order of the abelianization of a group counts the number of $1$-dimensional representations of that group, so naively I would expect that a small abelianization would leave room for larger dimensional representations, but the abelianizations of the dihedral groups have order either $2$ or $4$, which is almost as small as it gets. Meanwhile, the dimensions of the representations of symmetric groups gets arbitrarily large, and the abelianization there is order 2. I'm pretty sure it has a lot more to do with counting conjugacy classes than with the size of the abelianization.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein You are perfectly right. The expectation was indeed naive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comments indicate, the example of the dihedral groups shows that you cannot expect irreps of dimension greater than $2$ without additional hypotheses, and that bounding the size of the abelianization isn't a particularly helpful hypothesis.

One thing to say is that if a group $G$ has $c(G)$ conjugacy classes and $a(G) = |G/[G, G]|$, then it must also have $c(G)$ irreps (I am working over $\mathbb{C}$ throughout), $a(G)$ of which are $1$-dimensional. Since the dimensions $d_i$ of these irreps must satisfy $\sum d_i^2 = |G|$, you can conclude by the pigeonhole principle that $G$ must have an irrep of dimension at least

$$\sqrt{ \frac{|G| - a(G)}{c(G) - a(G)} }.$$

As you can see, $c(G)$ has a much bigger influence than $a(G)$ on this bound. Conversely, if the maximum dimension of an irrep is $d$, then

$$c(G) - a(G) \ge \frac{|G| - a(G)}{d^2}.$$

For example, the symmetric group $S_n$ satisfies $c(S_n) = p(n)$ (the [partition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $n$) and $a(S_n) = 2$ ($n \ge 2$), so we conclude that $S_n$ must have an irrep of dimension at least

$$\sqrt{ \frac{n! - 2}{p(n) - 2} }.$$

As a subexample, when $n = 7$ this bound is

$$\sqrt{ \frac{7! - 2}{p(7) - 2} } = \sqrt{ \frac{5038}{13} } \approx 19.7$$

so we conclude that $S_7$ has an irrep of dimension at least $20$. [In fact](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_symmetric_group:S7) it has irreps of dimensions $20, 21, 35$. (Of course, for the symmetric groups we know the dimensions of all of their irreps via the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula), so we can say much more here.)

Another thing to say is that the dimensions $d_i$ of the irreps must also divide the size $|G|$ of $G$. This is a strong restriction if $G$ is, for example, a [$p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group), since it implies that the dimensions must themselves be powers of $p$.